# R write xlsx files converting blank cells in a numeric output

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, r-xlsx

I have a matrix like this

```
> df <- head( iris )
> df[2,3] <- NA
> df[2,5] <- NA
> df[3,5] <- NA
```

with some NA.
So, if I put convert NA like this

```
df[is.na( df )] <- "#N/D"
```

df becomes a character matrix and when I write.xlsx my file excel contains a error message because doesn't recognize the numeric format. If I put logical NA in this way `df[is.na( df )] <- NA` and I write.xlsx I get a matrix output with blank cells. How can I obtain a matrix with "#N/D" and with the numeric format?

Comment: What package are you using that has the `write.xlsx` function?

Comment: @MrFlick Google says xlsx, added the tag.

Comment: I use the library openxlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an impression that setting `keepNA = TRUE` will solve your problem. According to the documentation of the `openxlsx::write.xlsx()`:

> **keepNA** If TRUE, NA values are converted to #N/A in Excel else NA cells
>   will be empty. Defaults to FALSE

An example is here:

```
# generate test data with NA values
test_df <- iris
test_df[c(1, 3, 7), ] <- NA
# write the file
write.xlsx(test_df, file = "test.xlsx", 
    keepNA = TRUE)
```

Does it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I don't know why but I tried all day showNA=TRUE